# PHPExcel not working in linux

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for exporting my data and the dynamically generated graph to the excel sheet. But it is not working on linux. i tried it on windows and it works but not on debian. specially the $objectwriter->save(str_replace('.php','.xls',*FILE*)) is not executed. I have tried so many things but didn't worked.
any possible solutions?

Comment: Is error reporting activated?

Comment: Please update your post to define "is not working." What do you expect to happen, and what is happening now? You said "I have tried so many things"; Please tell us what things you tried so we do not duplicate your effort.

Answer (score 2):

PHPExcel has the following requirements. Please make sure that your Linux box meets all these requirements:

```
PHP version 5.2.0 or higher
PHP extension php_zip enabled *)
PHP extension php_xml enabled
PHP extension php_gd2 enabled (if not compiled in)
```

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Requirements&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score -1):

I Solved this problem by

Enabling `zlib.output_compression` through

> CPANEL -> MultiPHP INI Editor -> Select Domain

**Cent OS**

php_zip - `enabled`.
php_xml - `enabled`
php_gd - `enabled`